# How to forward data to another action using Forward Plugin and read it there in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, forward, zend-controller, zend-controller-plugin

I have two actions in a controller: `actionA()` and `actionB()`. Dependent on a condition the `actionA()` should return a `ViewModel` object or be forwarded to `actionB()` (and return its result):

class MyController extends AbstractActionController {

```
public function aAction() {
    ...
    $data = ...
    ...
    if (...) {
        $result = new ViewModel(array(
            'data' => $data,
        ));
    } else {
        $result = $this->forward()->dispatch('MyModule\Controller\My', array(
            'action' => 'b',
        ));
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I tried it with

```
        $result = $this->forward()->dispatch('MyModule\Controller\My', array(
            'action' => 'b',
            'data' => $data,
        ));
```

But I have no idea, how to fetch this data now.

I'm sure, it's possible. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function bAction() {
        ...
        // so:
        $params = $this->params()->fromRoute();
        // or so:
        $params = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParams();
        ...
    }
```